# Which symphony does Artemis Fowl listen to increase his thinking capacity while planning his next move?

Tags: artemis-fowl

I remember that at one point, to make a counter-move in an ongoing plot, Artemis closes himself in a room and makes lot of arrangements with Butler's help to let his brain function at maximum.

One of the things he does is listen to a music record. It was either Mozart or Beethoven. I wanted to know the exact song.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Artemis Fowl: The Time Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_Fowl:_The_Time_Paradox)

> *"Plotting music, he thought. I need plotting music. He selected
>   **Beethoven’s Symphony No. 7** from his vast selection of mental music and
>   listened to it as he thought."*

Comment: Just an addition, Is this the only place its mentioned or were there any other such occurrences??

Comment: That's the sole mention of Beethover by name. There are two other references to musical symphonies in the same book series - "*That music is familiar because I composed it. “Siren Song” from my unfinished Third Symphony."* (TAC), "*He focused on the high end of his intellect, solving unprovable theorems with large cardinals and composing an ending for Schubert’s unfinished Symphony No 8."* (TTP),